# Executable RMI JAR file ClassNotFoundException for Stub

Tags: java, jar, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I have a working RMI server program, which I can compile and execute directly from the .class files.

However, when I am trying to create a JAR files for each of these programs, I got a `ClassNotFoundException: ChatImpl_Stub` leading to a `RemoteException` on execution.

My manifest is (plus an empty line at the end) :

```
Main-Class: Server
Class-Path: chat-RMI-common.jar
```

Where chat-RMI-common is a JAR file containing the Chat Interface for the client.

I successfully created the JAR with :

```
jar cvmf ..\MANIFEST.MF chat-RMI-server.jar *.class
```

The server JAR does contain ChatImpl_Stub. However the exception shows up when I am trying to launch the JAR file :

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:chat-RMI-common.jar file:chat-RMI-server.jar"
    -Djava.security.policy=..\security.policy
    -jar chat-RMI-server.jar
```

The exception appears when the `Naming.rebind` function, involving ChatImpl, is called (at the beginning of the program).

My security policy :

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

What am I still forgetting? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a good look at the stack trace. The Registry can't find the class. It needs to be on the Registry's CLASSPATH. So you either need to start the Registry with the right JARs on its CLASSPATH, or, better still start it inside the server JVM, with LocateRegistry.createRegistry().

Comment: It works now, I chose the lazy option (createRegistry()), thanks. Any idea how I can embed the java.codebase and java.security.policy options in the manifest instead having a script to run the JAR ? PS: I will accept your answer, just want to try 1 or 2 things before ;)

Comment: You can't embed either of those things into the manifest, but you can set them as system properties first thing in your main(). You could look into using JWS, which lets you embed system properties into an XML file.

Comment: i am getting same error which jar files required for Registry class

Comment: @fanky How is anybody but you possibly going to know what is in your JAR files? The question is ridiculous.