# Local jar is included in WEB-INF/lib, but ClassNotFoundException is still thrown

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, rmi, classnotfoundexception

This is a web app, and every thing is packaged inside a war.

I was able to install a local jar called `remote_proxy-1.0.0.jar` into my maven project (It is included inside `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the produced artifact). This jar file contains interfaces `Task`, and `TaskRunner`, and the `TaskRunner` implementation class `TaskRunnerRemoteObject`. Everything compiles, and the app can be deployed. Below is the bootstraping code used to start the RMI server

```
package rmi;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
public class ProcessInit {

    public static Process startRMIServer(ManagedExecutorService pool, String WEBINF, int port, String jar) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        Path wd = Paths.get(WEBINF);
        pb.directory(wd.resolve("classes").toFile());
        Path lib = wd.resolve("lib");
        String cp = Stream.of("javabuilder.jar", "remote_proxy.jar", jar)
                .map(e -> lib.resolve(e).toString())
                .collect(joining(File.pathSeparator));
        pb.command("java", "-cp", "." + File.pathSeparator + cp, "rmi.BootStrap", String.valueOf(port));
        while (true) {
            try {
                Process p = pb.start();
                pool.execute(() -> flushIStream(p.getInputStream()));
                pool.execute(() -> flushIStream(p.getErrorStream()));
                return p;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Retrying....");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void flushIStream(InputStream is) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcessInit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


public class BootStrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Instantiating a task runner implemenration on port: "  + port );
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");
            TaskRunner runner = new TaskRunnerRemoteObject();
            TaskRunner stub = (TaskRunner)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(runner, 0);
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            reg.rebind("runner" + port, stub);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BootStrap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `WEB-INF/lib`

[image: Inside <code>WEB-INF/lib</code>]

When this class is executed, it throws this error which I don't understand why, because the local jar `remote_proxy-1.0.0.jar` is included in the classpath, I don't have any compile error, yet, still get this exception.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: remote_proxy.TaskRunnerRemoteObject`

Comment: are you building a fat jar? Or do you deploy the binary on some RMI server product? The WEB-INF/lib folder will not be evaluated for standard-jars. I know only of WAR files, where this folder will be added to the application class path by the application server (tomcat, jetty, ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executable RMI JAR file ClassNotFoundException for Stub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001486/executable-rmi-jar-file-classnotfoundexception-for-stub)

Comment: The app is packaged as a war, and the `remote_proxy-1.0.0.jar` is just one of the local dependencies I have, I was able to use the web app with no `ClassNotFoundException` before when I did not use maven (I managed the dependencies manually)

Comment: Look in ~/.m2 dir. To install in a local repo you need maven. If it is not there you need to execute mvn install:file,,,,

Comment: Stack trace please. Is this happening to (a) the server (b) the Registry or (c) the client? NB `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");` is entirely pointless. Not sure of the point of `reg.rebind("runner" + port,...)` either. You don't need the port number in the bind-name.

Comment: Found the cause, I didn't tag my local jars with version numbers before I started using maven. And I didn't update the jar names to reflect the version number tags when I call the method `startRMIServer` above. Silly me. Thank yall for your time

Comment: @EJP  our web app must spawn many processes to run matlab-compiled-to-javacode due to its process-wide locking mechanism in order to support multiple requests, so we need each process to run one job, so `reg.rebind("runner" + port,...)` will guarantee uniqeness (newly spawned processes will bind to an unique name), we can't use threads, hence, multiple processes need to be spawned

Comment: But you don't need to start multiple Registries for that, or use multiple TCP ports either, and if you do start multiple Registries you don't also need multiple names.

Comment: @EJP So the problem is this. When the first user sends a request to perform an action that invokes a matlab-compiled-to-java jar, then subsequent users will be blocked until the first user request is fulfilled, even though the app server spawns multiple threads to serve many users at the same time, our app can technically serve only one user at a time, so to work around this issue in matlab runtime, for each such request, we start a new JVM, and execute the job inside that process, then return the result when done, so I am clueless as to how to achieve it w/o multiple registries.

Comment: Since each registry is bound to a JVM. Yes, I do destroy each process when it finishes

Comment: This is a new question. Ask it. Newly.

Comment: @EJP I posed a new question, hope you could shine some light on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233498/matlab-java-interoperability